# Water leaks through the base of the window through a hole during hard rain. Is this normal?

Tags: windows, leak

I noticed that when it rains hard, our windows leak water from the hole in the picture, is this normal? I already removed the water though in the picture.

[image: Hole in the base of the window where water goes in during hard rain]

[Other side of the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dq9I.jpg)

[image]

[image: holes to the outside]

Comment: That type of vent hole is normally at the top of the frame. Can you see outside? They should have a cover like the world's smallest lean-to roof, so falling water doesn't ingress. Being at the bottom, though, water could splash up off the window-sill.

Comment: Weep holes are normal at the bottom of add on storm windows (the old triple track aluminum kind).  They are there to allow any rain or moisture that may condense between the panes to run out and not accumulate.

Comment: Is the hole on the inside or the outside? Are there holes on the outside?

Comment: The weep holes I mentioned earlier are on the outside of the window.  There should never be any water coming through the window or it's frame into the inside of the house.

Comment: I once had similar windows in a property I rented.  They leaked like crazy.  The place developed mold.

Comment: On the other side of that hole, there is a like a plastic cover. I will post the picture later.

There is also a 2 holes where you pour water, it will go outside the window.

Comment: I already posted the picture. On the otherside of the hole , there is a black cover. And there is also a hole to let the water go out in the last picture.

Comment: Any additional comment on my new pictures?